# Simulating the motion of a satellite approaching Mars

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy, physics

I am very new to Python and have produced the following code, but it isn't working.

This code is attempting to map the motion of a satellite approaching Mars at variable `y` and `x` distances (i.e. 2 dimensional space). For now, Mars is considered stationary.

```
import scipy as sp
import numpy as np
import pylab as pl
import scipy.integrate as spi

G=6.67*(10**-11)
mm=6.4*(10**23)
#^mm is the mass of mars and G is the gravitational constant    

def f(b,t):


    xx=b[0]
    vx=b[1]
    yy=b[2]
    vy=b[3]

    ax=-(G*mm*b[0])/((b[0]**2) + (b[2]**2))**1.5
    ay=-(G*mm*b[2])/((b[0]**2) + (b[2]**2))**1.5


    return [vx,ax,vy,ay]

t=sp.linspace(0.,10000000.,1000)

xx0=[800000., 0., 10000, 0]

soln=spi.odeint(f,xx0,t)

print soln

x=soln[:,0]
v1=soln[:,1]
y=soln[:,2]
v2=soln[:,3]

pl.figure(1)
pl.plot(x,y)
pl.xlabel("x displacement")
pl.ylabel("y displacement")

pl.show()
```

This plots a straight line graph... perhaps I am misunderstanding the physics, but is there a problem with the code?

FYI - I have calculated the equations for acceleration using the Newton's law of gravitation and some laws of geometry. I'm mainly asking about issues in the code, but if any physicists out there notice any issues in the physics, then I'd love to hear them!

Comment: Aren't you missing t inside the function?

Comment: I don't have scipy so I can't run the code but... are you sure it's not working?  That is, you plot the trajectory, and it should be a straight line because you give it no initial velocity so it just falls straight down?  Try `plot(t, y)` and see if it's accelerating, and also try giving an initial `x` velocity.

Comment: Cheers yes I had just realised that earlier, too many numbers, that's correct thanks.

Comment: @tcrules: so is your problem solved?  (Also, what's the power of 1.5 for?)

Comment: @tom10: yes, I got hung up on the code and the physics to ignore the fact that I hadn't set the initial conditions sensibly. Incidentally, the answer given by Greg is very interesting. I knew the code wasn't perfect, so that sorted it out very well. The power of 1.5 => the component of the gravitational force in, for example, the x direction is Fgrav*cos(theta). Using geometry, cos(theta) is x/sqrt(r) where r is the resultant displacement (i.e. the hypotenuse of the triangle connecting Mars and the satellite). Fgrav=(Gmm)/r**2. So multiplied together on the bottom that's r**2 * r**0.5 = r**1.5

Comment: @tcrules: I see.  I hadn't examined the parens close enough (though I think the math in your explanation is off.. should be `r*r**2=r**3=(r**2)**1.5`.  Just as a tip, this would have been much easier to read, understand, and debug using your assigned variables, say `r2 = xx**2 + yy**2` and `(G*mm*xx)/r2**1.5`.

Answer (score 2):

If it gives you peace of mind at all I checked the equations and they are correct (not that you had any reason to doubt yourself). :)

The reason I think things are going awry is firstly that with such large quantities as `G * mm~10**10` you have to be very careful with initial conditions, an order of magnitude difference in your initial conditions can be the difference between a satellite orbiting mars and one outside the solar system. Secondly even when a sensible solution is found (which I believe your initial conditions to be) once the equations get close to `(x=0, y=0`) things get singular and you end up with huge accelerations leading to the satellite quickly vanishing of the local scale.

To fix this you could place a suitable check in the function that x,y are not close to zero and if they are, somehow end the ode solver.

Secondly when solving problems of this kind it is sensible to use [nondimensionalisation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nondimensionalization). This is a method in which you rescale the dependant variables `(x->x', y->y')` such that the primed versions are of order unity.

In your case I would simply ignore the time coordinate and let 
x = x' * L
y = y' * L

where L is a characteristic length scale. If you substitute this in your equations you will end up with a term `G * mm / L**3`. Set the characteristic length such that this quantity is unity: `L = (G * mm)**(1/3.0)`.

This has the advantage that the solver will find it easier to handle the numbers giving a speed increase. Now the only difficulty is in setting suitable initial conditions which are done by simply taking reasonable values e.g xx=10km and rescaling xx' = xx/L etc.

Using this method I can get your code to do a nice orbit.

[image]

Comment: could you elaborate on what you mean by setting L? I can't quite follow what you are saying. For instance the power third.

Comment: Sorry it was a bit late when I wrote this. [Here is the derivation](http://imgur.com/P0NJuAe) I figured this was the easiest way to share it. I was being lazy before with the time. You can check this works by calculating the units of L (remembering the t=t') and getting a length. This is a common technique for these types of problems.

Comment: Thank you that's great, however, I just noticed in my code, it should return [ax,vx,ay,vy], not what I've written. So that changes a bit of it

Comment: Are you sure about that? It should be the derivatives of `b = [xx, vx, yy, vy]` which are `[vx, ax, vy, ay]` unless I am missing something.

Comment: No you're right, it was fine, my demonstrators told me otherwise, spent hours destroying it, then fixing it, until I realised they were talking rubbish. S'all good.